# Panorama background horizontal stretch

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I'm trying to set background for panorama control by using this code:

```
<phone:Panorama.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BgImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"></ImageBrush>
</phone:Panorama.Background>
```

The BgImage property is filled once application is started. Image is different based on screen resolution of the device. The problem is that once backgound is set it gets shrinked by witch to single sreen width. So when I swype to next item background is not moving.

It seems like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/0743ee59-f407-4e8a-afc8-93569698a924/) bug that was for wp 7.1. Is it fixed in wp8? How do I set different images based on device resolution if such bug is still not fixed?